# Can't use TensorFlow Variable Twice

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get acquainted with TensorFlow, and I'm not sure about placeholders, variables and such. To make things easy, I tried to create a very simple calculation - a placeholder and a variable that is just the placeholder times two.

I've put everything in a function, like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def try_variable(value):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, name='x')
    v = tf.Variable(x * 2, name='v', validate_shape=False)

    with tf.Session() as session:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        session.run(init, feed_dict={x: value})
        return session.run(v)
```

I then call the function:

```
print(try_variable(80))
```

And indeed the output is 160.

But when I call it again:

```
print(try_variable(80))
```

I get an error:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype double

What am I missing?

Comment: In addition to Matan Hugis answer I would strongly advice to read more about the general concept of Tensorflow. One place to start might be [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs). It can be quite confusing when starting out to get your head wrapped around the concept of computational graphs. You should see python only as a meta language to define such graphs and initiate evaluation. It is really not more than an interface for controlling actual Tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I'm taking one of Deeplearing.ai's courses and their introduction to Tensorflow is really minimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you're creating a new variable and placeholder each time you call the function, so on the second time you call the `try_variable` function you actually have 2 placeholders and 2 TensorFlow variables! `x`, `x_1`, `v`, `v_1`.

So, on the second time you run the init operation, you provide the initial value only for placeholder `x_1` which is now binded to python variable `x`.

If you want to print the name of all the Tensors in the current graph, you can call

```
print [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

If you still want to create 2 new tensors each time you call the function, one option is to reset the default graph with the command  `tf.reset_default_graph()` 
each time the function is called - it is highly unrecommended.